# PHP - How to get the selected item from dropdown menu populated from query before POST

Tags: php, mysql, image, drop-down-menu

I would like to know how do I get the selected name from a dropdown menu, being populated by a query using phpmyadmin, to display a picture according to the selection.

For example, if the users selects "Mountains" from the drop down menu I want to be able to use that value and make another query to get the specific image URL from the database and display it, and every time the user changes selection the image changes accordingly.

And yes, I know, mysql commands are deprecated.
If you need any more details let me know.

```
<select name='picker'>";
<?php   
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('...');
$sql = "...";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
        }

          $selectoption = $_REQUEST['picker'];
      mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
      mysql_select_db('...');
      $sql3 = "...";    
      $image = mysql_query($sql3);
?>

<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
```

Comment: Ellaborate please, and thanks.

Comment: `mysql` is not *almost* deprecated it **is** deprecated and your code will stop functioning when your server admin upgrades to PHP 7

Comment: Thanks for the info @Kuya, editing post right now.

Comment: @user3190636, bind `<select>` with jQuery Change function, for 2nd query use Ajax inside change function to fetch data and show the image

Comment: @Shehary Can you give an example? or point me in the right direction with a tutorial from another website or something. I am not familiar with jQuery nor Ajax.

Comment: @user3190636, give me a moment

Comment: I can't think how phpmyadmin fits in to all this

Comment: @user3190636 check answer

Comment: @Strawberry it is where the client has all their databases stored. We are currently working on updating the structure, software, and codes.

Comment: The client has their data stored within a mysql database sitting on a server somewhere. PHPMyAdmin is merely a tool for the administration of said database. I very much doubt that you're doing anything to PHPMyAdmin - although you may be using it to access and modify the MySQL schema.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 Files

- main.php
- fetchimage.php

Note: Both files should be on same location, if root folder they look like this

```
main.php
fetchimage.php
```

if inside folder assuming folder name is alpha then

```
alpha/main.php
alpha/fetchimage.php
```

Now create `main.php` file and put following `PHP` and `jQuery` code in it.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('...');
?>
<select name="picker" id="picker">
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

//Here Show the Images
<div id="imged"></div>
```

jQuery

```
//JQuery library always comes first.
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#picker").change(function(){
        var name=$(this).val();
        alert(name); //This will show an alert when value selected, remove this **alert** in production mode, use it only in development mode.
        var dataString = 'name='+ name;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "fetchimage.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#imged").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

More information about [jQuery change function](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp) and [Ajax Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp)

- Bind `#picker` change function with `<select>`
- Bind Ajax success function with `id="imged"` to display the image

Now create second file name `fetchimage.php` and put following code in it nothing else.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); //Put Database Connection Here
mysql_select_db('...'); //Put Database Name Here
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){  
        $selectoption = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $sql = "SELECT Image FROM table WHERE name = '$selectoption'";    
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        //This will show the image inside <div id="imged"></div>
        echo '<img src="'. $row["Image"] .'" alt="" />';
    }
?>
```

Side Note: keep in mind, `mysql` is deprecated, should start using `mysqli` now.

**MySQLi (Procedural Example)**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
//Conntection Credentials
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "databasename";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Run Query
$sql = "SELECT imagename FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["imagename"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

OP requested an example code and provided other detail e.g (database) via email.

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Shehary. I will try your code in the evening. I will post updates along the way. Thank you again.

Comment: Right now I'm having some problems. The data I want to retrieve from the DB is the URL of the image contained in the same row as the name. For example, the result from the query must be $result = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg" and then that string display it using <img src="$result">Do I have to modify the code?

Comment: you can modify the code according to your need and requirement

Comment: Not at this moment, it does not display the image yet. I have modified everything correctly to fit my databases,etc. but not working.

Comment: you can discuss anytime anything, which part exactly not working so will narrow down the issue

Comment: Ok the problem right now is that it does not display any images.  Do I have to change something in this line? echo '<img src="path-to-image/'. $row["image"] .'" alt="" />'; It is from the fetchimage.php

Comment: yeah the `path-to-image` where it is located, folder name or in root or where?

Comment: suppose you have images in folder name myimages in root so it will be like `<img src="myimages/'. $row["image"] .'" alt="" />`

Comment: The URL where the image is located is fetched from the internet, example.com/images/example/example/image.jpg. And that url is stored in the database as another column associated with the name from the drop down menu I am populating with a query.

Comment: then this just be the url `<img src="example.com/images/example/example/image.jpg" alt="" />` which you are fetching from database

Comment: The thing is that url changes for every option in the dropdown menu. I would need to put a variable inside src"here". But i dont know how to do it.

Comment: There is no variable to my knowledge. Can you help modify your code so that a variable is returned and displayed?

Comment: can you create a http://pastebin.com/ with complete code you tried so far along with the database structure so let me have look at the original queries and how you are fetching data from database

Comment: Sure, can you provide me an email? I dont want it to be too public.

Comment: can you send me again the previous link to keep working on the code? @Shehary

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax on select onchange event then change the content of the image.